# Find $y'$ if $y = \arcsin(x^{\frac{3}{2}})$

Tags: calculus

Why is the answer $\dfrac{3x^{1/2}}{2\sqrt{1-x^3}}$? I solved this and I ended up getting $\dfrac{3x^2}{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}$. I'm studying for my final exam and while I have the answer to this question, I'm interested in knowing how to solve the problem so I can learn. Can someone please guide/explain this problem to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the chain rule $$\frac d{dx} \sin^{-1}(x^{3/2})=\frac 1{\sqrt{1-(x^{3/2})^2}}\frac d{dx}(x^{3/2})\\=\frac 1{\sqrt{1-x^3}}\frac 32x^{1/2}$$

Comment: Thank you to you and to everyone else for explaining the problem!

Answer (score 2):

$$y = \sin^{-1}(x^{3/2})\\\sin y = x^{3/2}$$

Differentiate with respect to $x$

$$\cos y\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac32x^{1/2}\\\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac32x^{1/2}}{\cos y}$$

What is $\cos y$? Draw your triangle.

[image]

$$\cos y = \sqrt{1-x^3}\\
\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac32x^{1/2}\cdot\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^3}}$$

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you've learned that
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\arcsin x=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
By the chain rule,
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\arcsin\left(x^{3/2}\right)=\dfrac{d}{d(x^{3/2})}\arcsin\left(x^{3/2}\right)\times\dfrac{3x^{1/2}}{2}\\
\implies \dfrac{d}{dx}\arcsin\left(x^{3/2}\right)=\dfrac{3x^{1/2}}{2\sqrt{1-x^{3/2}}}$$

Comment: In case you haven't seen the derivative of $\arcsin$ before or (like me) can't remember it every time, I find it really useful to remember the general rule $$[f^{-1}]^{\prime}(x) = \frac{1}{f^{\prime}(f^{-1}(x))}$$ which you can derive without too much ado by differentiating both sides of the equation $$f(f^{-1}(x)) = x$$ Certainly, remembering is more efficient in exam situations but in a tight scrape these things can be quickly derived or checked (probably at the end of the exam when you have already answered all the questions you feel confident with ;) )

Comment: @Shai That's what I do in any test! :-P